# Azure Archive Operations and pricing

Tags: azure, storage, archive

We are looking to move approximately 1 PB of data to Archive Storage. One of the options we have been considering is GPV2 storage with Standard Performance and Archive access. I have some questions about pricing. I used the pricing calculator at:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/calculator/

The data that will be archived is large image files as well as contract documents. From my reading, block blobs would probably be optimum for archival. Is this right?

In a simple scenario, I would like to upload a 100 MB imagery file. I would have to have an empty blob in a container and use set blob tier to set it to either hot or cool. I would then copy the file and then use set blob tier again to change it to archive. How would Azure handle the copy? How many blocks would the file be broken into? I have read that each putblock will be counted as one transaction and the final PutBlocklist will be counted as one transaction. How many operations will be required? If the price is $1.10 for 100,000 operations what kind of cost can I estimate? Also, what would be the cost for changing the tier from hot or cool to archive?

The more expensive task is reading the data. After 180 days and the client wants to read the data. The blob within the container would have to be set from archive to hot or cool right? It will then take time to rehydrate the data. What will be the cost? How will the file be handled when reading the data and how many get blob operations will be required? What other operations will be needed. Looking at the Azure pricing site, it says the cost is $55.00 for a 100,000 operations. As reading is supposed to be much more expensive, I suppose there will be a large number of operations.

For organizing the data containers would be necessary. Any help on container creation/deletion costs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions :). Let me try to answer them.

> From my reading, block blobs would probably be optimum for archival.
>   Is this right?

Yes. AFAIK, only block blobs are supported for archive tier.

> In a simple scenario, I would like to upload a 100 MB imagery file. I
>   would have to have an empty blob in a container and use set blob tier
>   to set it to either hot or cool. I would then copy the file and then
>   use set blob tier again to change it to archive.

You don't really have to do that. With [`Storage REST API version 2019-02-02`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/version-2019-02-02), you can directly upload blob into archive tier. No need for uploading them in hot or cool tier and then change access tier to archive.

> How many blocks would the file be broken into?

It depends. [`Maximum size of a block in a block blob can be 100 MB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/version-2016-05-31). Essentially the block size would depend on your Internet speed. I believe SDKs use 4MB block size.

> I have read that each putblock will be counted as one transaction and
>   the final PutBlocklist will be counted as one transaction. How many
>   operations will be required?

`Total operations required = number of blocks + 1 commit block list operation`. So if you have a 100MB blob and you split them in 4MB blocks, total operations required will be `25 (100 MB/4MB) + 1 = 26`.

> If the price is $1.10 for 100,000 operations what kind of cost can I
>   estimate?

In the example above it would be `$1.10 * 26 / 10000 = $0.000286` for a single blob.

> Also, what would be the cost for changing the tier from hot or cool to
>   archive?

Please see my 2nd answer. You don't really need to do that.

> The more expensive task is reading the data. After 180 days and the
>   client wants to read the data. The blob within the container would
>   have to be set from archive to hot or cool right?

That's correct.

> It will then take time to rehydrate the data. What will be the cost?
>   How will the file be handled when reading the data and how many get
>   blob operations will be required? What other operations will be
>   needed. Looking at the Azure pricing site, it says the cost is $55.00
>   for a 100,000 operations. As reading is supposed to be much more
>   expensive, I suppose there will be a large number of operations.

You can find this information on [`Azure Storage Pricing`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) page. Pricing depends on the region where data is stored so it basically would vary.

> For organizing the data containers would be necessary. Any help on
>   container creation/deletion costs would be helpful.

Again you can find this information on storage pricing page. Container creation is a single operation and I believe container deletion is a free operation.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I have read that the maximum size of a block Blob is 4.95 TB and that each blob has 50,000 blocks with a size each of 195 MB. For REST versions the maximum Blob size is 195 GB and with 50,000 blocks with a size of 4 MB. If we would be reading 5 100 MB files from a 195 GB Blob, it would be broken into (500/4 + 1) 126 blocks. This would be 126 operations. So the cost would be: $55.00 X 126/100,000 = $0.07. Is this correct? This seems very cheap. I was expecting a higher cost when retrieving data from archive.

Comment: Few things: Max block blob size is 4.95 TB. I am not sure where you got this 195 GB number. Also, can you describe what you mean by `If we would be reading 5 100 MB files from a 195 GB Blob`? Each blob is a single file so if you have a 195 GB Blob there's only one file read operation. Now you can read 500 MB data from this blob but there is no such thing as `5 100 MB files from a 195 GB Blob`.

Comment: I read that the 195 GB max Blob size is for older REST versions. As each blob is a file, let's say we retrieve 100 100 MB files. With a block size of 4 MB would the number of operations = (100*(100/4 + 1) = 2600. The cost would be: $55.00 X 2600/100,000 = $1.43. Is this correct? The client will want to download files to local filesystem for distribution. What is the difference between read and data retrieval? Data Retrieval cost is $0.022 per GB. So 100 100 MB files = 10 GB. Data Retrieval = 10 * 0.022 = $0.22. Is this right? What would be the cost of downloading 10 GB to local filesystem?

Comment: You can find most of this information using calculator here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=storage.

Comment: Thanks. I have been referencing the pricing calendar. I need an est, of the cost to download files to a local filesystem for distribution. We are looking at Azure Archive as a solution for a client who needs archiving. I want to be able to give a price to help them with their decision. On the pricing calculator there is read and data retrieval. When would read be used and when would data retrieval be used? How much would it cost to download 100 100 MB files to a local filesystem. Read price: $0.004 / 10,000 operations. Data retrieval: $0.022 / 1GB My apologies. I do not have Azure experience.